# Fedora 17 and Google Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, gcc, buffer, protocols, fedora

Has anybody had any trouble compiling protocol buffers using GCC on Fedora 17?  I believe I installed the correct packages

> sudo yum install protobuf*

The protoc compiler works fine but the generated class and header files don't compile when I add them to a fresh project.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh, I forgot to add -lprotobuf.  Nevermind!

Comment: How can I close the question?  It will not allow me to accept my own answer for 48 hours

Comment: You should be able to delete, first the answer, then question. If it doesn't work, it will be voted to be closed, and later deleted by the community.